# Run DITA OT in Mac OS?

Tags: dita, dita-ot

The DITA OT documentation has quite a bit of information about how to run the DITA OT in a Windows environment, but not much at all about running it in Mac OS. What is the procedure for running it in Mac OS (Mountain Lion)? Especially if you need to set environment variables (which is kind of tricky in Mac OS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DITA-OT installation for OS X is documented in [DITA-OT user guide](http://dita-ot.sourceforge.net/1.7/readme/installing-minimal-package-on-linux.html).